# Generate a dynamic condition to filter the data from user string like min > 0 and max <= 100 - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a case like where end user will enter a string in input field like 
**"(min > 0) and (max <= 100) and (average > 10)"**. I want convert this string into a possible conditions to filter the API response.

For example, my API response will be

```
{
   "result":{
      "name1":{
         "min":20,
         "max":30,
         "average":15
      },
      "name2":{
         "min":20,
         "max":30,
         "average":15
      },
      "name3":{
         "min":40,
         "max":40,
         "average":20
      },
      "name4":{
         "name":"name4",
         "min":50,
         "max":50,
         "average":25
      }
   }
}
```

I need the user inputs to converted to a way (like objects) so that I can apply that on the response. I tried using regexp to find the matches but I am not able to do. Please suggest.

Comment: This is JSON. You don't need a regex, just parse it and use a `for in` loop

Comment: Use a dropdown for min, max, avg, =, >, ... and an input for the number

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way it works is that you write some code, and when you get into trouble you can ask for help. You can read more at https://stackoverflow.com/help-how-to-ask

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would let us understand the real question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following.

- Create a function that takes 2 inputs the response object and the filter String
- In the function, update the string so that all the **and's** are replaced with **&&** and the variables in string is are accessed like keys from an object. Please note, this name should be same as the one that will be used in the function to evaluate the expression
- Use **Object.entries** to create an array of all the entries in object and then on the array use **Array.reduce**, to reduce the array into an object along with filtering the items in array that match the criteria. To evaluate the expression use `eval`

```js
let resp = {"result":{"name1":{"min":20,"max":30,"average":15},"name2":{"min":20,"max":30,"average":15},"name3":{"min":40,"max":40,"average":20},"name4":{"name":"name4","min":50,"max":50,"average":25}}};
let filterStr = "(min > 0) and (max <= 100) and (average > 10)";

function filterResult(obj, str) {
  str = str.replace(/\(/g, "(v.").replace(/and/g, "&&");
  return Object.entries(obj.result).reduce((a,[k,v]) => {
    if(eval(str)) a.result[k]=v;
    return a;
  },{result:{}});
}
console.log(filterResult(resp, filterStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to achieve what you are trying, without using any regex.

P.S.: eval is not recommended by most of the developers

```
const yourConditionString = "average > 20"
const filterArray = Object.keys(jsonData.result).reduce((arr, name) => {
let min = jsonData.result[name].min
let max = jsonData.result[name].max
let average = jsonData.result[name].average
return arr.concat(eval(yourConditionString) ? jsonData.result[name] : [])
}, [])
```